# Proxy error 502 aws after configuring .ebextensions

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, model-view-controller, proxy

I've deployed my Java web application to a AWS server, but I get an 502 proxy error like this when making a get request:
*The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /product.
Reason: Error reading from remote server*

The database connection works fine if the application is deployed locally with an online database.
I've tried to configure .ebextensions and my YAML file looks like these:
option_settings:
      option_name: Timeout
      value: 1000

This is my draft version of my site and you can see the error code: http://platformaruralpreno.eu-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/product

Comment: How are you deploying this (Tomcat/Docker/JavaSE + Spring boot)?  Are there any error logs from the Elastic Beanstalk Instances?

Comment: My application is deployed on Tomcat and here is my error log file from Elastic Beanstalk: https://ufile.io/7kdnm (last 100 lines)

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/apache/commons/logging/Log;` - your environment is not complete.

Comment: I've tried adding commons logging to my Maven dependency folder, but there is no a solution for me. Still get the error